# What is Difference between <a></a> and [url] [/url]?

Tags: html, anchor

Some websites use [url]website address[/url] in their text area, and their is no option to add an anchor text in it, can someone please explain it to me? I am very confused between  and this [url][/url]. I know how html anchor tag works but dont know about the second one. Thanks

I tried googling it, couldnt find any solution, expecting someone to explain it to me

Comment: _Some websites_ > this needs context. The URL in the text area you just used to post this question does not behave like that, for example. So it all depends on the [WYSIWYG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG) the site it using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<a>` is an HTML tag, whereas `[url]` is a BBCode tag.

[HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML) is a core web technology, which can be rendered by any web browser; [BBCode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BBCode) is much more limited in scope, being used by some sites to allow a limited, safe subset of HTML functionality, without allowing users to do things they shouldn't be able to (such as running scripts or messing with the site styles).

Comment: thanks, this is what I was looking on the internet didn't know about BBcode.

Answer (score 0):

`<a>` is HTML tag

`[url]` is BBCode tag.

They are used in different contexts.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BBCode